# How to add libreoffice 5.0 links to dash

Tags: 14.04, package-management, libreoffice, unity-dash

I have removed libreoffice 4.2 from my ubuntu 14.04 machine by using:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
```

And then I have installed libreoffice 5.0 extracting files from the downloaded package, and using the following command in the DEB folder

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

I can open openoffice 5.0 aplications using the terminal, but they do not appear in the unity dash.Even worst, the applications are not set as default to open office documents.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it by uninstall all 4.4 packages via synaptic. After logout and login again short-cuts to 5.0 where in dash

Comment: I have percipitate myself ,  login off and on again did the trick -.-